# Several errors in Sitecore Master server keepalive.aspx - The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable

Tags: configuration

I am getting several exceptions on the **CMS Master** server, such as the one shown below.

```
ManagedPoolThread #12 00:08:09 ERROR Exception in UrlAgent (url: /sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx)
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.
Source: System
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(String url, NameValueCollection headers)
   at Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent.Run()
```

My Sitecore CMS is version 7.0  I have separate Master Server and Content Delivery servers configured as well. 
This error **does not** occur within the **Content Delivery** servers

Any ideas what could be be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried the solutions provided on Sitecore's knowledge base website? See https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/376036.

Comment: I am getting a HTTP 503, which is not one of the scenarios in your reference article

Comment: Just a thought...if this is an internal environment, check if the app_pool identity is an AD/Domain user account and the password has expired. - That is only if your organization has password policy in place.

Comment: Check information information agents and tasks here:
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/repost-all-about-sitecore-scheduling-agents-and-tasks You can find agent in sitecore.config

Answer (score 1):

You need to add localhost as a binding and scheduled the UrlAgent to use the localhost address.

Comment: Could you please add an example of what you mean by "scheduled the UrlAgent to use the localhost address"? With a configuration example, preferably.